# nVidia Driver version numbering confusion

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

When I look at the driver properties for my video card (Card is a GeForce 8300GS), the version is listed as 8.17.11.9728, and according to Windows Update it's the latest version.

When I check directly with nVidia, the latest version is 258.96.

Is there any sort of correspondence between the Windows version and the nVidia version?

Comment: The version number for the driver package and the version number for the specific driver are not necessarily the same.  If you install the 258.96 package you should see the exact same thing in properties.  (I can't confirm this right this second unfortunately but that sounds like the right number...it will be close at any rate.)

Comment: Right you are.  I'd accept that if it was a an answer - the 258.96 "package" installs 8.17.12.5896.